# Which is better way to pass data to event handler: by function closure or custom data-attribute

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, custom-data-attribute

I have a question about passing data to event handlers. 
Isn't it better to attach a custom data attribute to a component and get it from the received event object in the handler, instead of creating new functions on each render to closure the data.
What are the drawbacks of this method? Because I couldn't find any information in the official docs.

```
const Ids = [0, 1];

const Comp = (props) => {
    const onClick = useCallback((e) => {
        console.log(e.target.dataset.index);
    }, []);

    return (
        Ids.map(id => (
            <div data-id={id} onClick={onClick} />
        ))
    );
};
```

Comment: I think Dan referred somewhere to the usage of data-attributes as not recommended. You could move `<div data-id={id} onClick={onClick} />` to react component and pass `id` and `onClick` as props. You can even memoize `id` along with `onClick`

Comment: hey, did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

While making use of `data-` attributes is generally accepted in vanilla JavaScript/HTML development, the React way of doing things would be to pass the required data as part of your event handler method's parameters.

This is actually stated on the react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html#should-i-keep-data-in-custom-attributes) itself:

> No. We don’t encourage you to keep data in DOM attributes. Even if you
>   have to, data- attributes are probably a better approach, but in most
>   cases data should be kept in React component state or external stores.

Therefore, while react does not explicitly restrict you from doing so, the recommended practice would be to avoid using `data-` attributes unless
necessary.

Building onto your example, this is how it should be done:

```
return (
    Ids.map(id => (
        <div data-id={id} onClick={() => onClick(id)} />
    ))
);
```